# How to NOT select empty string

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, orm

We have the following JPQL:

```
Select distinct sys.ipAddress from SystemLog sys where sys.ipAddress is not null and sys.ipAddress is not empty
```

And this generates the following `mysql`  statement.

```
select
    distinct systemlog0_.ipAddress as col_0_0_ 
from
    SystemLog systemlog0_ 
where
    (
        systemlog0_.ipAddress is not null
    ) 
    and (
        exists (
            select
                systemlog0_.id 
            from
                SystemLog systemlog0_
        )
    )
```

This obviously doesn't work and returns empty string instead of omitting it. 
However, I am looking for something like this to be generated:

```
select distinct ipAddress from SystemLog where ipAddress is not null and ipAddress <> '';
```

However, I can't figure out why our jpa query doesn't generate something simliar like that.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that you are misusing `IS [NOT] EMPTY` that is used to check whether a **collection association path** resolves to an empty collection or has at least one value. From the JPA specification:

> #### 4.6.11 Empty Collection Comparison Expressions
>
> The syntax for the use of the
>   comparison operator **IS EMPTY** in an
>   *empty_collection_comparison_expression*
>   is as follows:
>
> ```
> collection_valued_path_expression IS [NOT] EMPTY
> ```
>
> This expression tests whether or not
>   the collection designated by the
>   collection-valued path expression is
>   empty (i.e, has no elements).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> SELECT o
> FROM Order o
> WHERE o.lineItems IS EMPTY
> ```
>
> If the value of the collection-valued
>   path expression in an empty collection
>   comparison expression is unknown, the
>   value of the empty comparison
>   expression is unknown.

In my opinion, you should just use the `<>` comparison operator:

```
select distinct sys.ipAddress 
  from SystemLog sys 
 where sys.ipAddress is not null 
   and sys.ipAddress <> ''
```

Comment: "IS NOT EMPTY" doesn't seem to be working to detect blank strings. I'm using hibernate and JPA. Is the <> operator ok for jpql?

Comment: @Amalgovinus Yes, `<>` (and `!=`) work to check whether a string is empty in JPQL. See here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-conditional-expressions